# Convert BitmapImage with Filter to BitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have a BitmapImage and I applied a ShaderFilter to it:

```
            var bm:BitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bm.source = resizedBitmapData;
            bm.filters = [filter];
```

I tried copy the bitmapImage into a bigger image as overlay:

```
            bm.addEventListener(FlexEvent.READY, function (event:*):void {
                var bmd:BitmapData = bm.bitmapData;
                backgroundBitmap.bitmapData.copyPixels(bmd, 
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, bmd.width, bmd.height),
                    location);          
            });
```

It worked but what "bmd" contains is the original image before the filter was applied. What I wanted is to grab the resulting image after applying the filter. Is this possible?

I was trying ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData() but BitmapImage doesnt seem to be  an IBitmapDrawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try adding it to a sprite and then render the sprite if your way is not working allready...

something like

```
 var helper:Sprite = new Sprite();
 helper.addChild(bm);
 var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bm.width,bm.height);
 bmd.draw(helper);
 backgroundBitmap.bitmapData.copyPixels(helper, 
       new Rectangle(0, 0, helper.width, helper.height),location);
```

have you anyway checked the filter applies and is rendering with the wanted result? ;)

Comment: the attrib "helper.bitmapData" doesnt seem to exist. yup the filter works just fine when displayed on screen. the filter is ShaderFilter.

Comment: sorry fast shot.. draw() method should do

Comment: btw is there a reason you are not using any displayobjects?